# Weird %MINIFYHTML code showing just before </body> tag

Tags: php, wordpress, minify, cloudflare

The following code is showing on certain pages of my wordpress site.

`%MINIFYHTMLba8fd15a026c51b9ab71a637e3fe71401%%MINIFYHTMLba8fd15a026c51b9ab71a637e3fe71402%%MINIFYHTMLba8fd15a026c51b9ab71a637e3fe71403%%MINIFYHTMLba8fd15a026c51b9ab71a637e3fe71404%`

I am using Thesis 2.0 and wordpress 3.5

I can't google the error properly because of the % sign.

I have disabled cloudflare performance, and w3 total cache, so there should be no caching or minifying going on.

Comment: Looks like something left over from W3C Total Cache.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I usually lurk and find all my answers via search, so this is new to me. I'll check my past questions and see what I can do. As for W3C... I'll check again, could it be related to anything in the htaccess (I really don't think so).

Comment: Doubtful. Worst case, you could review at footer.php. Something is getting *hooked* in.

Comment: Thanks Jason. It's still there, over 2 hours after disabling all caching. I'll check my custom functions file and see if anything is getting hooked in from there. I'll look at the footer template too.

Comment: http://buddypress.org/support/topic/minifyhtml/

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your W3 cache (Section: minify HTML) and then check again.